# How to calculate sequence rise/fall intervals

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling with how to determine, from which element on, the sequence is rising or falling. For example, if I have a sequence with a generic term
$$a_n = \frac{n^2 -6n+4}{n+1}$$
the next element will then be
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^2-6(n+1)+4}{(n+1)^2+1}.$$
If I want to calculate the rising and falling of the sequence, then I do
$$a_{n+1} - a_n$$ which gets me the numerator to
$$n^2+3n-9=0.$$
I calculate the solutions from the numerator and I get
$$n_1 \approx -4.854, n_2 \approx 1.85.$$
The $n_1$ is not suitable so the only valid solution is the $n_2$, but I do not really understand, how to interpret that, will the sequence star rising from the term 1 or 2? How does the value of the solution explain the rising or falling of the sequence?

Comment: You can decide between $n=1$ or $2$ by just calculating the values there. Check $n=3$ to be sure.

Comment: When you talk about the sequence "rising" and "falling", do you mean increasing and decreasing?  I.e. a sequence is increasing if $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$?

Comment: Also, the denominator of $a_{n+1}$ seems to be incorrect.  It should be $(n+1)+1$, not $(n+1)^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of looking at $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is fine.  If this is positive, then the sequence is increasing; and if it is negative, the sequence is decreasing.  Hence the goal is to determine the sign of this expression.  Expanding it gives

\begin{align}
a_{n+1} - a_n
= \frac{(n+1)^2-6(n+1)+4}{(n+1)+1} - \frac{n^2-6n+4}{n+1}
= \frac{n^2 + 3n - 9}{(n+1)(n+2)}
= \frac{(n-r_1)(n-r_2)}{(n+1)(n+2)},
\end{align}
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the numerator, i.e.
$$ r_{1,2}
= \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{(-3)^2-4(1)(-9)}}{2(1)}
= -\frac{3}{2} \pm \frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2}
\approx -4.85, 1.85. $$

A quick-and-dirty way to determine when the expression $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is positive or negative is to sketch the graph.  This function has zeros at $r_1$ and $r_2$, poles at $-1$ and $-2$, and approaches a horizontal asymptote of $y=1$ at both positive and negative infinity (since
$$ \frac{n^2 + 3n - 9}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{n^2 + \text{lower order terms}}{n^2 + \text{lower order terms}} \approx 1
$$
when $n$ is large).  Since all of the roots and poles are of order $1$, the graph crosses the $x$-axis at each of these points, which leads to a picture similar to the following:

[image]

Note that this picture is intentionally sloppy, and likely misses many aspects of the graph (e.g. I doubt that the function actually dips below $y=1$ between the poles), but it shows the relevant information for *this* problem.  If a more accurate graph is required, more tools are needed.

This function is positive when the graph is above the $x$-axis, and negative when it is below the $x$-axis.  That is, the expression $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is increasing when
$$ n \in (-\infty, r_2) \cup (-2, -1) \cup (r_1, \infty)
\approx (-\infty, -4,85) \cup (-2, -1) \cup (1.85, \infty). $$

Given that this is a sequence of numbers, it might be possible to simply assume that $n \ge 0$, in which case the poles at $-1$ and $-2$ don't have to be thought about very carefully, and the behaviour of $a_{n+1} - a_n$ farther to the left can be ignored (this actually would have made it possible to simplify the problem earlier, too).

Hence $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is

- positive when $n > r_1 = -\frac{3}{2} + \frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.85$, and
- negative when $n < r_1$.

This means that the sequence is decreasing when $n \le 1$, and increasing when $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Graph the elements of the sequence and it becomes obvious.

[image]

The sequence is increasing from $a_2$ onward, in the sense that every subsequent term is larger. Note that $2 = \lceil 1.85 \rceil$, i.e. that root rounds up to $2$. (This logic should hold in general since, if $x$ is a non-integer, then $\lceil x \rceil$ is the next largest integer, and hence the next possible index for a member of the sequence.)